# How to get vendor_module/view/frontend/web/images path within Setup/Patch script?

Tags: magento2, url, patches

I need to get the url of the image located in the module.

I need to run a Patch script because I am updating a cms block with an additional image.

The image path I am getting is localhost/pub/static/version1655667432/frontend/_view/en_US...

But when I look at the pub folder, the path should be
localhost/pub/static/version1655667432/frontend/**default**/en_US...

```
    try {
        $this->_appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_appState->getAreaCode();
    }

    $params = array('_secure' => $this->request->isSecure());
    $madeInUsaImgPath = $this->assetRepo->getUrlWithParams('Collins_ShowOnAll::images/made-in-usa.png', $params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create any Setup/Patch scripts

For create your own extension you just need to create 2 files in module

1. Create `registration.php`

   ```php
   <?php
   declare(strict_types=1);

   use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

   ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Acme_StackExchange', __DIR__);
   ```
2. Create module declaration `etc/module.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="Acme_StackExchange">
           <!-- optional dependencies -->
           <sequence>
               <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
           </sequence>
       </module>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create frontend resource like `view/frontend/web/images/file.png`

And access file with `Acme_StackExchange/images/file.png` from skin

If you have more specific question, please update your question or specify in comment

**[Update]**

The path to static file contains deploy version in URL and I don't suggest you to use full URL.

For CMS Block/Page you can use directive `view`

```html
<img src="{{view url='Acme_StackExchange::images/file.png'}}" alt/>
or
<img src="{{view url='Acme_StackExchange/images/file.png'}}" alt/>
```

If you want to use in template

```
<img src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl("Acme_StackExchange::images/file.png"); ?>" alt=""/>
```

Comment: I updated the questions description.

Comment: See updated comment, i hope this will help